# Using boost::asio::signal_set with SIGTERM or SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

There are examples for the signal_set to catch SIGTERM or SIGINT. Is it considered safe to also register SIGABRT or even SIGSEGV? Because the signal_set needs an io_context I'm not sure if that context is still valid when SIGSEGV happened.

Also I'm not sure about registering SIGTERM or SIGINT with the signal_set and SIGSEGV with normal std::signal. The documentation states that multiple registering of signals is not possible. Is it forbidden to call std::signal after any invocation of signal_set?

Comment: Which documentation "states that multiple registering of signals is not possible"? What does tht even mean, because many documentation examples and some overloads explicitly accept multiple signals (`signal_set(io_context, SIGTERM, SIGINT)`). By the way, `SIGSEGV` is not something you can ever expect to usefully handle.

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/signal_set.html in the section "Multiple registration of signals".

Comment: So, that explicitly says that both multiple registration is fine and also multiple signals can be handled. Just *not* mixing with manual use of POSIX signal API. With this is mind, can you make your question more concrete? E.g. create a self-contained minimal example of what you would want to have, and what part is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You correctly hold the intuition that SEGV cannot be recovered from. At the very least, the program cannot resume (best case, attempts to do so will result in repeated SEGV).

You also correctly noted that you should not be meddling with the POSIX signals interface directly if you're using Asio's support already.

All the rest is pretty well-defined:

- having multiple signal-sets
- handling many more than 2 signals per set
- handling signals multiple times in different sets
- awaiting the same set multiple times

Here's demo that forces a SEGV 6s in:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85779ff96c7ecd35)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using std::this_thread::sleep_for;

struct Demo {
    Demo(asio::any_io_executor ex, char const* name) : set(ex), name(name) {
        for (int num : {SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2, SIGHUP, SIGPIPE, SIGSEGV})
            set.add(num);
        wait_loop();
    }

  private:
    asio::signal_set set;
    char const*      name;

    using error_code = boost::system::error_code;

  public:
    void wait_loop() {
        set.async_wait([this](error_code ec, int num) {
            printf("%6s signal %s (%s)\n", name, ec.message().c_str(), ::strsignal(num));
            sleep_for(200ms);

            if (num != SIGTERM)
                wait_loop();
        });
    }
};

int main() {
    asio::thread_pool p;

    auto ex = p.get_executor();
    Demo first(ex, "first");
    Demo second(ex, "second");

    second.wait_loop(); // doubly await the second set for good measure

    sleep_for(6s);
    static void (*force_segv)() = nullptr;
    force_segv();

    p.join();
}
```

With interactive live demo:

[image]

Comment: > *SEGV cannot be recovered from* Where is this stated? After SIGSEGV handler returns, instruction caused SEGV is restarted, at least on x86_64. E.g. if SEGV is caused by write to read-only memory region and handler remapped it as read-write, process continues to execute.

Comment: Sure, that is, IFF you can figure out the cause of the SEGV, which isn't the case. In principle you *have to assume* that there may be unintended corruption. E.g. my example relies on "controlled SEGV" to make it reasonable that the rest of the process may keep on working. I would never do that in real life. Perhaps I **might** do a best-effort stack-dump/trace kind of operation

Comment: I got your point, thanks for explanation.